# Javascrript onclick change image title

Tags: javascript, variables

I need to display the title of a currently loaded video under the player. The user clik on a thumbnail to load the video on the jwplayer. I can only load the first title.

```html
<div>Now playing: <span id='nowPlaying'>My 40th Aniversary</span> </div>


<script type="text/javascript">
function changeTitle(){
   var video = document.getElementById('vidTitle').getAttribute('title');
   document.getElementById('nowPlaying').innerHTML = video;
}
</script>

<!-- body of my pge -->

<h2>Trips</h2>
<ul>
  <li> <a href="javascript:loadVideo('rtmp://OnDemand/triptoElgin.mp4');"> <img   src="http://www.example.com/images/triptoelgin.jpg"  id='vidTitle' onclick='changeTitle()' title="Trip to Elgin "/></a>Trip to Elgin</li>

<li> <a href="javascript:loadVideo('rtmp://OnDemand/triptoWaco.mp4');"> <img  src="http://www.example.com/images/triptowaco.jpg"  id='vidTitle' onclick='changeTitle()' title="Trip to Waco"/></a>Trip to Waco</li>
</ul>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
```

How can I add a variable to load the next video title?  I tried this, but it gives undefined value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In HTML, the `id` attribute must be unique.  Right now, when you're calling `document.getElementById('vidTitle')`, the browser is picking the first one no matter what.  If you want to identify which of the images you clicked on, I would send `this` to the `changeTitle` function like so:

## JavaScript

```
function changeTitle(element){
  var video = element.getAttribute('title');
  document.getElementById('nowPlaying').innerHTML = video;
}
```

## HTML

```
<ul>
  <li> <a href="javascript:loadVideo('rtmp://OnDemand/triptoElgin.mp4');"><img src="http://www.example.com/images/triptoelgin.jpg" id='vidTitle1' onclick='changeTitle(this)' title="Trip to Elgin "/></a>Trip to Elgin</li>
  <li> <a href="javascript:loadVideo('rtmp://OnDemand/triptoWaco.mp4');"> <img src="http://www.example.com/images/triptowaco.jpg"  id='vidTitle2' onclick='changeTitle(this)' title="Trip to Waco"/></a>Trip to Waco</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I was just answering this and I missed the 2 same ids, lol.  +1 I missed that answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
    function changeTitle(element){
  var video = element.getAttribute('title');
  document.getElementById('nowPlaying').innerHTML = video;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div>Now playing: <span id='nowPlaying'>My 40th Aniversary</span> </div>


<script type="text/javascript">
function changeTitle(video){
   var video = video.getAttribute('title');
   document.getElementById('nowPlaying').innerHTML = video;
}
</script>

<!-- body of my pge -->

<h2>Trips</h2>
<ul>
  <li> <a href="javascript:loadVideo('rtmp://OnDemand/triptoElgin.mp4');"> <img   src="http://www.example.com/images/triptoelgin.jpg" onclick='changeTitle(this)' title="Trip to Elgin "/></a>Trip to Elgin</li>

<li> <a href="javascript:loadVideo('rtmp://OnDemand/triptoWaco.mp4');"> <img  src="http://www.example.com/images/triptowaco.jpg" onclick='changeTitle(this)' title="Trip to Waco"/></a>Trip to Waco</li>
</ul>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
```